# How can I use docker inspect to figure out my IP

Tags: linux, docker

As a beginner, I read Docker High Performance met a problem.
After  I've linked my container ,I confirmed the link had been contribute.

`sudo docker inspect -f " {{ .HostConfig.Links }}" destination [/source:/destination/webapp]`

Then I tried to check my IP but nothing appeared

`sudo docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}"    source`

I tried another way.

`~$ sudo docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}'    source`

Finally i checked my iptables

`$ sudo iptables  -L DOCKER
Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination`

Please tell me how can I get my IP. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You mess with the quotes, it is single quotes, not double quotes

`docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' container_id_or_name`

will display it